# Reaching all of Canada's "land's end" spots - which ones are marked?

Tags: canada, national-parks, landmarks, geography

I have been to [Cape Gaspé at the end of the Gaspésie peninsula](http://www.openstreetmap.org/node/878547660#map=11/48.7675/-63.9761).
When I got there, I was pleasantly surprised that the national park personnel set up a sign marking the land's end. It felt like reaching a particular landmark.

[image: Cape Gaspé land's end]

I am interested in reaching as many "land's ends" as possible and I was wondering if there are other such signs set up in Canada. I expect there could be some in Labrador, Newfoundland, British Columbia or in the northern territories.

So my question is, are there other such "land's ends" in Canada, marked by national park personnel?
Is there a list of these landmarks?

Comment: Super question! I'm drooling to put a bounty on this one. Question: Is the white on blue a signature of the Canadian Park Service? Is that how one would recognise the signs?

Comment: Funny land's end, that. Ile d'Anticosti is just over the horizon, St. Pierre et Miquelon is a bit farther, and of course there's Newfoundland and Labrador.

Comment: :) @GayotFow Yeah, I would say that's the sign we would be looking for (that's the only such sign I have seen though). The red chairs are definitely their signature at least

Comment: Cape Gaspe isn't even the easternmost point of mainland Quebec.

Comment: @DJClayworth that's a detail, but Cape Gaspe is in an actual national park ([Forillon National Park](http://www.pc.gc.ca/eng/pn-np/qc/forillon/index.aspx))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are parks at at least two of Canada's extremities: Point Pelee (the southernmost point on the mainland) and Cape Spear (the easternmost point). There are signs on both pointing this out.

- [Point Pelee](http://www.canada-photos.com/picture/point-pelee-national-park-welcome-sign-leamington-ontario-5898.htm)
- [Cape](http://explore150.tigweb.org/en/cape-spear-lighthouse) [Spear](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f9/Cape_Spear_Sign.JPG)

The absolute southernmost point is [Middle Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_Island_(Lake_Erie)), which is an uninhabited nature reserve.

The Westernmost point is [Boundary Peak 187](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Boundary_Peaks_of_the_Alaska%E2%80%93British_Columbia/Yukon_border) in the Yukon. It is not part of a park, and is marked only by a surveyors marker.

The northernmost point  is far into the arctic. I'm pretty sure there is no sign.